# cannot use import statement outside a module with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, package, next.js

I need to import a npm package but failed when I use "import" statement
like this

```js
import { cuteLuna } from 'lunacomponent';
```

and I got an error : cannot use import statement outside a module

after I change it to dynamic import, it works.

```js
const cuteLuna = dynamic(() => import('lunacomponent').then((a) => a.cuteLuna), {ssr: false});
```

My question is, why should I use dynamic import instead of usual import?

thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Next.js is a framework that runs on **server** & **client** side it needs to consume the proper module styles for each.

Server side runs on Node, therefore your lib must expose a [commonjs](https://flaviocopes.com/commonjs/).

From your error I can guess that your `lunacomponent` lib is not exporting cjs files, therefore it fails on the **server**, when you use `dynamic` with `ssr:false` you tell Next.js to skip server-side run, therefore you don't have the same error.

I wasn't able to find this `lunacomponent` lib on the public npm registry, therefore I can't check my assumption.